# How to add CategoryAxis in amcharts?

Tags: amcharts

I need to be able to draw a vertical line in the graph and seems easy enough using this information: http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/vertical-or-horizontal-lines-or-fill-ranges/

However, I am not finding a way to add the CategoryAxis property to the existing chart.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an object-based configuration, when you create a chart instance it will already have categoryAxis property set:

```
var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

// chart.categoryAxis is already set and populated with a reference to CategoryAxis object
// we can set its properties, including guides
chart.categoryAxis.guides = [ {
  "category": "2001",
  "toCategory": "2003",
  "lineColor": "#CC0000",
  "lineAlpha": 1,
  "fillAlpha": 0.2,
  "fillColor": "#CC0000",
  "dashLength": 2,
  "inside": true,
  ""label"Rotation": 90,
  "label": "fines for speeding increased"
}, {
  "category": "2007",
  "lineColor": "#CC0000",
  "lineAlpha": 1,
  "dashLength": 2,
  "inside": true,
  ""label"Rotation": 90,
  "label": "motorcycle fee introduced"
} ];
```

If you are using JSON-based approach, the guides config needs to go into "categoryAxis" object:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "guides": [ {
      "category": "2001",
      "toCategory": "2003",
      "lineColor": "#CC0000",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "fillAlpha": 0.2,
      "fillColor": "#CC0000",
      "dashLength": 2,
      "inside": true,
      ""label"Rotation": 90,
      "label": "fines for speeding increased"
    }, {
      "category": "2007",
      "lineColor": "#CC0000",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "dashLength": 2,
      "inside": true,
      ""label"Rotation": 90,
      "label": "motorcycle fee introduced"
    } ]
  },
  // the rest of the chart config
  // ...
};
```